# Trouble displaying data from ajax json parse

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

This is the link to my codepen: http://codepen.io/dsemel/pen/VamEyE

This is the section of code that seems to be the problem:

```
function success(position){

var WeatherKey = '6068dffce2f44535a07202457162103';

var lat = position.coords.latitude; 

var long = position.coords.longitude; 



   var weatherUrl = "http://api.apixu.com/v1/current.json?key=" + WeatherKey +     
                     "&q=" + lat + "," + long;



$.ajax({
url : weatherUrl,
type: 'GET',
dataType : 'json',
success : function(data) {
var city = data['location']['name'];
    var tempFar = data['current']['temp_f'];
    var img = data['condition'][0]['icon'];

    var desc = data['condition']['text'];

$('#weatherInfo2').text(tempFar);  
}

 });
}
```

Comment: The tempFar data will not display on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code works fine you just missed a small thing in your code i corrected that
http://codepen.io/rahulchaturvedie/pen/RagGdR

```
$.ajax({
  url : weatherUrl,
  type: 'GET',
  dataType : 'json',
  success : function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    var city = data['location']['name'];
    var tempFar = data['current']['temp_f'];
    var img = data.current.condition.icon; // correct this
    var desc = data.current.condition.text; // correct this
    $('#weatherInfo2').text(tempFar);  
   }   
  });
```

Comment: i am glad i could help.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you check your developer tools console when you encounter these errors. Your code is throwing this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`.

The `condition` object is part of the `current` object, therefore you have to access the `current` object before accessing the `condition` object.

[Updated working codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aNwmMr)